# Using a Point to set position

Tags: actionscript-3, point

Is there a way to set the x and y at the same time using the Point object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not unless you use the constructor. The Point class does have an offset(x,y) function, so you could do something like point.offset(-1*point.x+newX, -1*point.y+newY), which would have the effect that you desire.

Is there a particular reason you want to set it at the same time or are you just trying to write compact code?

Comment: @redconservatory, just remember that fewer lines and faster/better are not equivalent ^_^

Comment: Another idea is to extend Point to add this functionality -- you could add a set(x,y) function on it. This would be better than my hackish offset() idea and would allow you to compact your code without unintentionally obfuscating your logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
var p:Point;

p = new Point(5,10);
// after that
p.x = 27;p.y = 34;
```

You can have multiple commands in a same line, if all you want is to write compact code. So this way, you avoid doing multiplications, that will just complicate your code and make it more unstable / slower.